# a design issue on a java class definition

Tags: java, class, constructor

With respect to following java program for checking palindrome, I do not understand why it has to include `private String pal;` in defining this class. Is that a design issue, will it cause any problem if removing this line of code?

```
public class Palindrome {
    private String pal;

    public Palindrome(String initPal) {
        pal = initPal.toUpperCase();
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome() {
        if (pal.length() <= 1) {    
            return true;        
        }
        char first = pal.charAt(0);
        char last = pal.charAt(pal.length()-1); 

        if (Character.isLetter(first) && Character.isLetter(last)) {      
            if (first != last) {        
                return false;           
            }
            else {      
            Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1,pal.length()-1));
            return sub.isPalindrome();  
            }
        }
        else if (!Character.isLetter(first)) {

            Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1));
            return sub.isPalindrome();     
        }
        else {

            Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(pal.substring(0,pal.length()-1));
            return sub.isPalindrome();      
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome p1 = new Palindrome("abcdcba.");
        System.out.println(p1.isPalindrome());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your class need some string attribute so the caller sets the string to be analyzed and then, make it check if it's a palindrome or not, right? Proper indentation helps on visualize what's the content of the class

Comment: what happens if you remove it :-) Simply try it

Answer (score 0):

It has to include that private field so that it can store the constructor parameter long enough to be used when someone calls the `isPalindrome` method.

Just look at all the places that `pal` gets used: these are all in the scope of the class's instance, but outside the scope of the constructor. If the field wasn't declared, there would be no way for `isPalindrome` to access this data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, all your Palindrome class is doing is checking if a string is a palindrome. Obviously, you don't need a private String pal for such a class.

In fact, you should make this class a utility class and instead have a static method like this-

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) 
    {
       // your logic here.
    }
```

You can then call this method like this -

```
 String string = "aabaa";
 boolean isPalindrome = Palindrome.isPalindrome(string);
```

There is absolutely no need to have an instance variable like pal if all your class is doing is checking whether a string is a palindrome.

Comment: In the end, if there's no attribute, shouldn't this become a method somewhere else? I mean, that class wouldn't be an abstraction of something, the dependencies wouldn't be injected, etc...

Comment: Yes, it could be put in a utility class.